# WPF - combine/link multiple styles into one

Tags: wpf, wpf-style

In my WPF application I want to style a data grid. For this I need several separate styles (sub styles), since they target different controls. Now I want to combine those into one style (main style) to set it in xml via `<DataGrid Style="{StaticResource MyDataGridStyle}">`

Pseudo code for sub styles:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <!-- sub styles -->
    <Style x:Key="RowStyle" TargetType="Row">...</Style>
    <Style x:Key="ColumnStyle" TargetType="Column">...</Style>
    <Style x:Key="ColumnHeaderStyle" TargetType="ColumnHeader">...</Style>
    <Style x:Key="SomeInnerElementStyle" TargetType="SomeInnerElement">...</Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Currently I'm combining the styles via

```
<!-- inside the ResourceDictionary -->
<!-- main style -->
<Style x:Key="MyDataGridStyle" TargetType="DataGrid">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource RowStyle}" TargetType="Row" />
        ... all other sub styles go here
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

Is there a more elegant way of including the sub styles in my main style? The `BasedOn` attribute forces me to specify the `TargetType` again, which is a pain and also I do not want to include "a new style based on the sub style" but just "the sub style".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the corresponding `Style` properties:

```
<Style x:Key="MyDataGridStyle" TargetType="DataGrid">
    <Setter Property="RowStyle" Value="{StaticResource RowStyle}" />
    <Setter Property="ColumnStyle" Value="{StaticResource ColumnStyle}" />
    <Setter Property="ColumnHeaderStyle" Value="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderStyle}" />
</Style>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this option only works for styles which have a corresponding property in the containing object (data grid in this case). However I have quite a few styles targeting inner elements (e.g. ComboBoxes in custom columns) which cannot be included this way.

Comment: @Thomas: In this case, there is mo more "elegant way".

Comment: I feared as much. Thanks anyway.